# Powershell - check for last time computers were restarted

Tags: powershell, restart

I need to make sure all computers are being restarted at least once a week, and I've been googling on it, and I found something, but it's... rather something simple, something... 1-timer... What I want is to make it a bit more advanced.

Here's the command I found online:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName <computername> : select cname, @(LABEL='LastBootUpTime' ;EXPRESSION=($_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)))
```

(I'm not sure if sharing the links is a good idea here, but I just googled for "check when remote computer was last restarted" and clicked on a link on enterprisedaddy)

I do not know anything about PowerShell, so I'm asking for your help. Also, it may be useful not only to me, but to others as well...

Here's what I want:

1. Create the *.ps1 file (I can do that) and make it run it 24/7
2. Instead of copying all computers each time, I want to append new computers to the list, because otherwise, the list would be very, very long... and I don't want to be deleting a whole bunch of computers and making sure only 1 copy is left and deleting all other every day...
3. Export the list into either *.txt or (even better) *.csv
4. At the end of the day, the *.ps1 would create a new *.txt or *.csv file and start it all over. In a new file. Of course leaving the old one (or all others, starting day 2...) for the review...

I understand there's very little hope, but if you can help me - great. If not - well, it may take forever to google for it all, but in the end, I may be able to find it all myself... Although there is even less hope here...

To be fair, all I need is to see the last time the computers were restarted, and that's all, so if you know of an easier way - I'm ready to read about other ideas.

Comment: "all I need is to see the last time the computers were restarted" - but you've already found a solution to that through google? So what is the question here? :)

Comment: WMI is disrecommended. instead, use the CIM commands ... they are generally faster AND they return datetime objects instead of filetime objects. [*grin*] try something like the following to get the LastBootUpTime >>> `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OPeratingSystem -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME).LastBootUpTime` <<<

Comment: My question is how to make it run 24/7 and append new computers, not write all computers over and over. Also, at the end of the day, the script would create a new document and the process would start again. The code I found runs just once and it doesn't export the results to a document.

Comment: [There are plenty of examples all over the web for this use case.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+get+last+restart+days%27&t=hk&ia=web)

Comment: In my answer you can just reuse the same file name instead of generating it dynamically.  You'd have to add `-Append` to the `Export-Csv` command.  However, it will take more work if you want to load up existing data update existing computers and add new ones.  I'm hesitant to append the existing answer, we're really not supposed to write code for you...  That said, You'd use `Import-Csv` to get the existing data.  And you need to know what or where is going to be the authoritative source of machines to query.  Are you going to get them from AD a text file etc???

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer, but should help you toward your goal.  If I'm interpreting your question correctly you want to check the last boot up time daily and report machines that haven't rebooted in the last 7 days.  That data should then be stored in a csv file.

So this is actually quite easy to do, and PowerShell is a great place to do it.  However, you have to "develop" on top of what you've already discovered.  Set goals and meet those goals.

A start might be something like:

```
$Today      = Get-Date
$ReportDate = $Today.AddDays( -7 )

$OutputCsv = ("C:\Temp\" + $Today.ToString( "yyyy-MM-dd"  ) + ".csv" )

$BootTimes =
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName pyex06 | 
Select-Object PSComputerName, @{ LABEL='LastBootUpTime' ;EXPRESSION={ $_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime) } }

$BootTime | 
Where-Object{ $_.LastBootUpTime -lt $ReportDate } |
Export-Csv -Path $OutputCsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note: I didn't test this just hammered it out quickly for demonstration.

What's happening:

1. Get the current date.
2. Use the current date to calculate the date boundry earlier than which you want to report on.
3. Use the data again to derive a string suitable for naming a somewhat unique output file.
4. Do the query, add the LastBootUpTime property.  Note: I made several syntax corrections there.
5. Now run the results through a `Where{}` statement that will filter for boot times more than 7 days old, and export to a CSV file.

Again this is just a start.  You will need to add an ability to work against more than one computer,  You'll need to think about what your input is going to be for that.  You will probably also want to add error handling as WMI (and later CIM) connections can and do fail.

An aside: `Get-WMIObject` is deprecated.  It's been replaced by `Get-CimInstance`.  `GetCimInstance` will return a LastBootUpTime property as an actual date, with no need to add the property.  That command would look something like?

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName ComputerName | 
Select-Object PSComputerName,LastBootUpTime
```

All of these things are very well documented.  In fact I'm sure somebody has even published a script doing exactly what you want.  You have to have some idea of how building a larger script will progress and hopefully I've given you that much.  It's a series of solving individual issues and putting those solutions together etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it tomorrow. I know a bit of batch scripting, but PowerShell - it's a brand new level for me. I know just a few very, very basic things in it, but in the end, all I need is listed above. I don't think I will use it ever again... I'll let you know tomorrow if it worked or not. But thanks a lot for hints. It doesn't cover everything that I want, but it's a good start.

Comment: OK, so, I tried to run it (a bit modified; as I have a whole bunch of computers, it's easier to just copy the list of the computers to a text file and have '$BootTimes =
Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\computernames.txt"' but I get the next error: "File "C:\***.ps1" cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system." How do I fix that?

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` or unrestricted.  You should google that, it may be controlled by your administrator, but is not strictly speaking a problem with the script.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, the WMI stuff is depreciated, and CIM is the new hotness going forward. Note that win using cross-platform PowerShell (PowerShell Core), the WMI cmdlets do not exist.

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
# Results
<#
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  1
#>


 (Get-Command -Name '*wmi*').Count
# Results
<#
21
#>



$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
# Results
<#
Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      0      3
#>


 (Get-Command -Name '*wmi*').Count
# Results
<#
0
#>
```

Secondly, the command you posted is not syntactically correct and thus would never work.

Lastly, always do the basic stuff first to make sure you are getting what you'd expect before taking the next step.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem |
Select-Object -Property '*'
# Results
<#
...
CSName                                    : Lab01
...
Description                               : 
InstallDate                               : 20-Jun-20 18:59:14
...
Distributed                               : False
LastBootUpTime                            : 13-Aug-20 01:00:42
LocalDateTime                             : 20-Aug-20 14:01:53
...
CimSystemProperties                       : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
#>
```

Note, you can get the dates directly with no conversions needed, then format as needed.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem |
Select-Object -Property CSName, LastBootUpTime, 
@{
    Name       = 'TimeSpanSinceLastRestart'
    Expression = {New-TimeSpan -Start $(Get-Date) -End $PSItem.LastBootUpTime }
}
# Results
<#
CSName LastBootUpTime     TimeSpanSinceLastRestart
------ --------------     ------------------------
Lab01  13-Aug-20 01:00:45 -7.15:02:24.1130902 
#>
```

As for this...

> My question is how to make it run 24/7 and append new computer

... just put in in a scheduled task (on each host or on an admin workstation where you get computer names from AD or from a file) and export to either a CSV or a file using the -Append parameter.

```
(Get-ADComputer).Name | 
ForEach{
    Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $PSItem |
    Select-Object -Property CSName, LastBootUpTime, 
    @{
        Name       = 'TimeSpanSinceLastRestart'
        Expression = {New-TimeSpan -Start $(Get-Date) -End $PSItem.LastBootUpTime }
    } | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\SystemRebootReport.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation -WhatIf
}
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Export-Csv" on target "D:\Temp\SystemRebootReport.csv".
#>
```

Just remove the -WhatIf to create the file.

**Update**

As for ...

> [So how do I use this implicit remoting instead then?]

...this is all detailed in the Powershell Help files, see

> [about_Remote_Requirements - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote)
>
> ['PowerShell implicit remoting active directory'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20implicit%20remoting%20active%20directory%27&t=hk&ia=web)
>
> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+implicit+remoting+active+directory
>
> https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/powershell-implicit-remoting-never-install-module-again
>
> [TechNet Install RSAT for Windows 10 1809 and 1903 and 1909 -
> automated](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Install-RSAT-for-Windows-75f5f92f)

Comment: As mentioned above, I have zero experience working with PowerShell. As a result, I just copied your script and edited it from "Get-CimInstance..." to Get-Content -Path "C:\...\computernames.txt" (otherwise the list of the computers would be way too long) and I get an error: The term 'Get-ADComputer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program.

Comment: No worries. The ADDS cmdlets only exist if you are on a system that has RSAT with the AD and DNS features enabled. This normally a domain controller, but you can enable the RSAT tools on Windows 8/10 or install them on Windows 7 and Windows 8 RTM. If you don't want to or can't install them, then you can use PowerShell implicit remoting to proxy those cmdlet to your machine for use. RSAT and PowerShell remote is fully documened on Microsoft websites, PowerShell tech docs, and all over the web and in videos on Youtube.

Comment: I'm afraid, RSAT is not an option for me. So how do I use this implicit remoting instead then?

Comment: Oh, and... I kind of hoped there is a way to make it something like "while(today=$today) run_this_command_over_and_over & export to_$today+csv.csv I mean, I'm sure "while" or analog can be used to keep the script running over and over, or, say, every 5 minutes. Or is it too hard to do/can't be done?

Comment: RSAT, not an option? What does that mean? It's built into Windows 10. You just need to install/enable it.  the Microsoft powershellgallery.com even offers a script to do this for you.  See my update of my answer.

Comment: Oh, so since I can just enable it in Windows 10... Then it may be an option. You were saying that normally I would run it from the domain controller... So you must have confused me here... Then yes, I may give it a try...

Comment: NO worries, and mea culpa on the confusion. You don't need to be on a DC to use them, but if you can't install them, you'd use remoting to connect to a DC and proxy those cmdlets to your machine, that are only available while you are in the remote session and use them just as you would on the DC. This is not just a ADDS thing. You can do this for any server resource you have access to for cmdlets, not on your machine, say like Exchange or SQL, SharePoint.